# FOR loop not looping

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I have the below script that uses 2 for loops. for some reason they loop is not looping

```
#! /bin/ksh
CURR_PATH='/main/nedcor/flexcube'


cd $CURR_PATH


for DIR1 in 'WIP' 'INPUT';do

    echo $DIR1
     for DIR in $(find . -name $DIR1);do


        RESULT=`ls -A $DIR | egrep -v "BKUP|BKP"`

        echo $DIR
        echo $RESULT
        echo $RESULT1
        if [ -z "$RESULT" ] ;
        then 
            echo "No Files found"
            exit 0
        else
            echo file $RESULT found
            exit 1
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: You need `$(find . -name "*$DIR1*")`.

Comment: it's not working                                                                                        $ cd /main/nedcor/flexcube
$ find . -name "INPUT"
./QA/Interface/BAEFT/INCOMING/INPUT
./QA/Interface/CARD/INCOMING/INPUT
./QA/Interface/CPS/INPUT
./QA/Interface/EPS/INPUT
./QA/Interface/GI/CARD/INCOMING/INPUT
./QA/Interface/GI/INCOMING/INPUT
./QA/Interface/NAMCLC/INCOMING/INPUT
./QA/Interface/NAMEFT/INCOMING/INPUT
./QA/Interface/NDLN/INPUT
$  but the output is

Comment: But output is $ ctrlM_chk_input_file.sh
/main/nedcor/flexcube/QA/Interface/BAEFT/INCOMING/INPUT
file BKUP found. Only the first item in the $DIR is being picked

Comment: What makes you think it's not looping? You have various problems, both serious (your script will break on file names with whitespace) and minor (you are not quoting your variables and you're using UPPER CASE names) but the loop itself will work as expected. Please [edit] your question and clarify how it is failing. Don't add extra information in comments, it is hard to read and easy to miss.

Comment: `find /main/nedcor/flexcube -regex ".*\(WIP\|INPUT\).*" ! -regex ".*BKUP.*\|.*BKP.*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be using `exit` inside your `for` loops - this causes the script to exit, and is why you're only getting one result.  You should be using `continue`, which will stop the current loop from going on, but will go to the next element in the `for` loop.

Swap both your `exit` statements to `continue` and you should find very different behavior, more in line with what you're looking for.